# How to protect static files with authentication in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am building a very simple Meteor app with the following situation: there are some static files in the backend (images, audio, video) that I need to include in my page, but I only want authenticated users to be able to access them. How can I do this?

I suspect I might be able to do this using routers but I haven't managed to get that running using the official documentation (or any other resource for that matter). If somebody could point me in the right direction I would be thankful.

Comment: Are the files already bundled during build time or are they dynamically added to your backend?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how secure you needed.
You may want to just hide/show the link then you can put those files in `public` folder and add some logic to the front-end to show/hide the files based on user's authentication state.
If you need it more secure then you you need to put those files behide APIs. You can use DDP apis (Meteor method or pub/sub) or you may use `webapp` to create api.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly 2 ways to do it:

1. obfuscate source urls
2. Only show to signed in users.
3. 

a) meteor-files: https://github.com/veliovgroup/Meteor-Files for overall file security.
b) CDN signed urls: root url remains the same but it requires a signature for every download/view. You can look at things like Instagram, FB etc.

2. Put images in pages on routes for only logged in users. If delivered from CDN, add policies to match your referrer/origin to disallow embedding of your images on other websites.

Comment: "Put images in pages on routes for only logged in users"

But the URL for the image is still publicly accessible, right?

Comment: Right ... with a comment. You can have an image, pdf or other documents behind a complex URL. Let's say, an invoice for me in PDF. It is up to me how secure the invoice link is, whether I share it with somebody else or not but there is no other user that will view my invoice. Think of it like the "anyone with this link" in Google Drive sharing (e.g. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lwDqjBGBliixaOmzQm5gxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyxxxxxyyyyyikNNSQR4H/view?usp=sharing). This is a case where number 2 works ok. I get access under my login to see my own documents distributed via urls that cannot be guessed.